# How to bring a minimized window into foreground on OS X

Tags: macos, finder

when I minimize an application window on OS X (10.6.2), e.g. Firefox, it does not show up anymore, when I "cycle" through the running apps with the apple+space key combination.

Is there another way to do this? Or a setting I can change, to make the app come back up from the dock when I give it focus with apple+space key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> combination to choose the application, then press <kbd>alt</kbd>  (while keeping <kbd>Cmd</kbd> pressed with the application selected) and release them both, the minimize window will be unminimized.

Comment: After about ten tries, I managed. Ok, it works but it is very difficult to get right, first because you need two hands and second because the cmd+tab combo will loop through all apps, so you have to get the timing right as well... No easier way?

Comment: Just found out, it also works with the tab released, which solves the timing issue... and with the alt key on the right hand side. I think I can get used to this then... Thanks!

Comment: OK, I see, it's not very clear, I'll edit my post. First, choose your app with Cmd+Tab, when it is done, just keep the Cmd key pressed, press Alt and release them both.

Comment: Also worth noting that on the new low-profile wireless keyboards the alt and option keys are shared so you actually have to press the fn key as well in order to press the alt key

Comment: Alt and Option have never been different keys on Mac keyboards. "Alt" is printed there for the benefit of people using Windows, as Option maps to Alt when used under Windows. You don't have to press Fn.

Comment: That does not work with Safari for some reason. At least not when there are multiple windows opened of which some are minimised.

Comment: Is this 10.6 only? I'm not able to get this to work in 10.5.

Comment: Nope, I did it too when I had 10.5.

Comment: didn't work for me either ...

Answer (score 5):

I use [Witch](http://www.manytricks.com/witch/), which basically is a document centric switcher as opposed to the app centric Command Tab. I have Witch assigned to Option Tab so I have the option of choosing which one I want to use.

Comment: This sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

If your windows minimize into the Dock (that is, they shrink to sit next to the Trash), you should be able to use Control-F3 (Control-Fn-F3 on Mac keyboards that have special hardware functions attached to the function keys) to switch keyboard focus to the Dock. Then you can use the arrow keys and space bar to restore the desired window.

It's not quite what you're asking for, but it might be easier than finding the right app with Command-Tab, then the right window with Option-Tab.